# Communication between two VMs using DNS Names

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, dns

First of all, apologies if this has been asked before.

Say I have Virtual Machines A and B, both running Linux. VM A will make accesses to a MySQL Server in VM B. In the Azure Dashboard, for both VMs, it shows an associated DNS name (obviously different for each VM). From a machine outside Azure, I can SSH into any of those VMs just fine, using those DNS names.

However, when I try to connect from VM A to the MySQL server in VM B (via MySQL client or with PHP functions) using the DNS name of VM B, about two in every five attempts to connect are successful. The remaining attempts state that the host is unknown (so VM A has a problem resolving the DNS name of VM B if I'm right).

I have been looking at the configuration files of MySQL and the hosts files of both VMs, but I haven't found anything so far that is able to explain *why VM A sometimes is able to connect to VM B MySQL via its DNS name and other times not. It seems completely spurious.*

I think I could resolve this if I replaced the DNS name of the MySQL virtual machine with its public virtual IP address. But then this would be problematic when the public virtual IP of VM B changes...

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a Virtual Network and add them to the VNET, to make the 2machines talk.

Comment: I will try that out later and post back the results. Still, do you have any idea why it is showing this seemingly-random behavior? And is it best to delete the VMs, create a VNET, create new VMs with the same VHDDS and add them to the VNET? 

That way they would communicate with fixed internal VNET ips and would still have their public VIP for accesses from outisde Azure?

Comment: It seems some throttling is applied with the Azure VMs regarding DNS queries, which explains why some queries work and some seem to fail at random. I was indicated towards your solution, ultimately, so I'm accepting it. "DNS query traffic is throttled per VM. If your application performs frequent DNS queries on multiple target names, it is possible that some queries may time out. A possible workaround is to reduce DNS query traffic from each VM and then retry the lookup." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156088.aspx